# How can I detect the error state of my DFA?

Tags: java, logic, dfa

Input template: 0+[0-9]+1+

Input events: A, B, C

Input string: C7584A7584AC7584A

I'm trying to find all the patterns (following the template) in the input string. The "0+" and "1+" are placeholders where it can be any letter from the events (A, B, C). So the patterns can be A+[0-9]+A+, A+[0-9]+B+, A+[0-9]+C+, B+[0-9]+A+, B+[0-9]+B+, B+[0-9]+C+, C+[0-9]+A+, C+[0-9]+B+, C+[0-9]+C+. All these regexes correspond to a DFA and are stored in a 2D matrix (3rows x 3columns).

Each time a pattern is found, a counter for that pattern in recorded. Also every time an element from the input string is consumed, the DFA only provides if the current state is success or not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            int _index = this.events.indexOf((char) input[i]);

            if (_index == -1) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.events.length(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.events.length(); k++) {
                        dfaMatrix[j][k].startTraversal(input[i]);
                        dfaMatrix[k][j].startTraversal(input[i]);
                    }
                }
            } 
            else {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.events.length(); j++) {
                    dfaMatrix[_index][j].startTraversal(input[i]);
                    dfaMatrix[j][_index].startTraversal(input[i]);

                    if (dfaMatrix[_index][j].isSuccess()) {
                        count[_index][j] += 1;
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    } else if (dfaMatrix[j][_index].isSuccess()) {
                        count[j][_index] += 1;
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.events.length(); k++) {
                        for (int m = 0; m < this.events.length(); m++) {
                            dfaMatrix[k][m].reinitialize();
                            dfaMatrix[m][k].reinitialize();
                        }
                    }
                    flag = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.events.length(); j++) {
                        dfaMatrix[_index][j].startTraversal(dfaMatrix[_index][j].getDfat(), input[i]);
                        dfaMatrix[j][_index].startTraversal(dfaMatrix[j][_index].getDfat(), input[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My expected results are:

```
[A][A] : 1
[A][B] : 0
[A][C] : 0
[B][A] : 0
[B][B] : 0
[B][C] : 0
[C][A] : 2
[C][B] : 0
[C][C] : 0
```

But I'm getting

```
[A][A] : 2
[A][B] : 0
[A][C] : 0
[B][A] : 0
[B][B] : 0
[B][C] : 0
[C][A] : 1
[C][B] : 0
[C][C] : 0
```

For some reason when the DFA is consuming the second C, the DFA is not reinitialising where logically it should be reaching error state. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?